# Table searching with multiple combobox php

Tags: php, filter

I have some codes to filter my table. it looks like this,it works fine.

```
if ($_REQUEST["brgy"]<>'') {
$search_city = " AND brgy='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["brgy"])."'";   
}
if ($_REQUEST["prk"]<>'') {
$search_prk = " AND prk='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["prk"])."'";  
}

if ($_REQUEST["gender"]<>'' and $_REQUEST["cstatus"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE gender = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["gender"])."' and cstatus = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["cstatus"])."'".$search_city.$search_prk;
}  
else if ($_REQUEST["gender"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE gender = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["gender"])."'".$search_city.$search_prk;
}

else if ($_REQUEST["cstatus"]<>'') {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE cstatus = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["cstatus"])."'".$search_city.$search_prk;
}
 else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE id>0 and status='active' ".$search_city.$search_prk;
}

$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
```

but if I will add this code it doesn't filter my table it displays nothing:

```
if ($_REQUEST["religion"]<>'') {
$search_rel = " AND religion='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["religion"])."'";    
}
```

I wonder what's wrong with adding it. I construct this again so it should understand well than before.

Comment: both the if and the while below are not correctly closed. What error are you getting?

Comment: it doesnt perform the filter. when i begin to filter it display no data.if ($_REQUEST["religion"]<>'') {
$search_rel = " AND  religion='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["religion"])."'";   
}×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission×An error occurred during comment submission

Comment: i reconstruct my code to understand it well,i hope so, sorry @briosheje i did'nt explain it well.

Comment: Do you have any sql error? you should be really careful when building the queries.. This code is really vunerable to **sql injections**, the first thing you should do is using a safer prototype to perform your sql queries, like mysqli_* or PDO. Apart from that, if the query is not successful the sql error usually contains an indication or a tip that can give you an idea. Also, are you sure that the coloumn name is religion?  If so, check what is the value of $_REQUEST['religion'] by echoing it. Perhaps $_REQUEST['religion'] is empty ;)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i don't get any errors at all, yeah i'm sure that my column name  is religion. i just add it up what you said.  thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using newer version of PHP it will be `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()`. You are also using it incorrectly. Read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp) to learn how to use it correctly.